# Swift - Linking UIViewController through code

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, edit, swipe

I'm trying to link an edit button back to my UIViewController (AddfreshreleaseViewController). This code shows the edit button on the left when you swipe the cell towards the right, but when I added in the 'performSegue' to try and get back to the UIViewController the app crashes every time I swipe towards the edit button now. Any suggestions on how I can get this working?

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?

{
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Update", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")
        success(true)

    })
    modifyAction.title = "Edit"
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "addFreshRelease", sender: self)

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])

}
```

Here's the code for I'm using for FreshReleaseTableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import UserNotifications

class FreshReleaseTableViewController: UITableViewController{

    var freshreleases = [Release_Date]()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    //create a new button
    let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    //set image for button
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Mic App Logo.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none


    //let button1 = UIButton()
    //button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editAction), for: .touchUpInside)

    //self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

}

/* @objc func editAction() {
    let viewController = AddfreshreleaseViewController()
    navigationController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}*/

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = Release_Date.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Release_Date>

    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "artist", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "album", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]
    do {
        freshreleases = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error {
        print("Could not fetch because of error: \(error).")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}


// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return freshreleases.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    let freshrelease = freshreleases[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0


    let artist = freshrelease.artist ?? ""
    let album = freshrelease.album ?? ""
    cell.textLabel?.text = artist + "'s \nnew album '" + album + "'\nreleases"

    if let date = freshrelease.release_date as Date? {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    } else {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
    }

    return cell
}


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}



// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if freshreleases.count > indexPath.row {
        let freshrelease = freshreleases[indexPath.row]

        // Remove notification
        if let identifier = freshrelease.release_dateId {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [identifier])
        }


        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        context.delete(freshrelease)
        freshreleases.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error {
            print("Could not save \(error)")
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    }
}



@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?

{
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Update", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")
        success(true)

    })
    modifyAction.title = "Edit"
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])

}

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

}
*/

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

}
```

And here's the code for AddfreshreleaseViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import UserNotifications

class AddfreshreleaseViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var artisttextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var albumtextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var releasedatePicker: UIDatePicker!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    releasedatePicker.minimumDate = Date()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@IBAction func saveTapped( _ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let artist = artisttextfield.text ?? ""
    let album = albumtextfield.text ?? ""
    let releasedate = releasedatePicker.date

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let newRelease = Release_Date(context: context)
    newRelease.artist = artist
    newRelease.album = album
    newRelease.release_date = releasedate as NSDate?
    newRelease.release_dateId = UUID().uuidString

    if let uniqueId = newRelease.release_dateId {
        print("The freshreleaseId is \(uniqueId)")
    }

    do {
        try context.save()
        let message = "\(artist)'s new album \(album) releases Today!"
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.body = message
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day],
            from: releasedate)
        dateComponents.hour = 09
        dateComponents.minute = 00
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents,
            repeats: true)
        if let identifier = newRelease.release_dateId {

            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                content: content, trigger: trigger)
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Could not save because of \(error).")
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("Added a Release Date!")
    print("Artist: \(newRelease.artist)")
    print("Album: \(newRelease.album)")
    print("Release Date: \(newRelease.release_date)")
}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}



}
```

So what I'm looking to do, is that when the edit button is pressed in the FreshReleaseTableViewController it brings up the AddfreshreleaseViewController.

However, the edit button is written in code rather than it actually being a bar button item.

And to make it more complicated, when a user goes to AddfreshreleaseViewController they enter information into three fields (artist, album, and release date) and it saves it on the FreshReleaseTableViewController. So when the edit button in the FreshReleaseTableViewController takes them back to the AddfreshreleaseViewController, I need the user information that was inputed (artist, album, and release date) to be in the three fields, so that the user can edit the fields if something was wrong with the initial input.

Comment: The details you haven't yet given matter. (1) Is `addFreshRelease` defined properly in IB? (2) You *are* defining this segue through IB, correct? (3) What *exact* euro are you getting? (4) Could you provide enough code for duplication on our part? (5) *"I'm trying to link an edit button back to my UIViewController...."* Focusing on just *that* piece, what are you trying to do? There are ways to "move data back" in the view controller stack. Again: it really gets down to detail you haven't yet provided.

Comment: As far as I know IB is defined correctly as addFreshRelease. I'm not getting an error message, the build works but when I swipe the direction to reveal the edit button, the app crashes.

In the app, the user provides information in three fields (in the addFreshReleaseViewController) and it saves it as a reminder when the date comes (in the FreshReleaseTableViewController). I'm trying to have the edit button (in the FreshReleaseTableViewController) go back to where they entered the information (in the addFreshReleaseViewController) so that they can change it if it were to be wrong.

Comment: What's IB? It's defined in the attribute inspector title as addFreshRelease

Comment: IB == Interface Builder. Back in the day (maybe Xcode 4?) there were two separate apps, Xcode and Interface Builder. Anymore, the easiest way to explain what "IB" is, are you "using a storyboard"? I think you are - and thus using "IB". It's impossible to *define and use* a segue (I believe you can almost define it but not use it) without a storyboard.

Comment: Now, I have code that uses (a) a storyboard with a navigation controller that works through three VCs. (Select, Edit Subject, Edit Other.) It uses a segue between all three - **and** if the user wishes to "flip/flop" between the two edits, it passes data *back* from the "Edit Other" to the "Edit Subject" VCs. Do you think that would help you? I'll gladly post it.

Comment: Last comment - in case I'm having communication issues with `addFreshRelease`, `addFreshReleaseViewController`, `FreshReleaseViewController`, and `FreshReleaseTableViewController`. Making it more generic - are you trying to pass something from the *second* VC back to the *first* VC when the user is "unwinding" the second VC from the stack?

Comment: I think it might help. Thank you

Comment: I edited the original post to provide more information

Answer (score 1):

Too little info, but I will try to guess the behavior you experience.

Nevertheless, why do you want to perfomSegue in the completion of the modifyAction? You should pop the current view controller using this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller

Example:

```
 _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: I provided more info, hopefully it'll clarify things

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure the exact nature of your issue, but if you are (a) using a Storyboard-defined segue to move data from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2` and then wish to (b) move edited data *back* to the first VC in the "unwind" usually done with the left hand navigation button, here's code the will do it:

In your first VC (`ViewController1`), define what you want from the second VC (`ViewController2`) and send `self` in the segue:

```
var someData:String!

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowViewController2" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
            vc.firstVC = self
        }
    }
}
```

And in your second view controller, define the first VC (as `weak`) and pass the data back in `viewWillDisappear` and the `UIViewController` property `isMovingFromParentViewController`.

```
weak var firstVC:ViewController1!

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if isMovingFromParentViewController {
        firstVC.someData = "Hello world!"
    }
}
```

Comment: I provided more info, hopefully it'll clarify things